# pass variable to swf file

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a Action Script 2.0 code (.swf flie) Loading the Image In a continues manner . I want the swf receive variable from html code and load image

```
var current_loader:Number = 1;           
var current_img:Number = 0; 

this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_01', 999);              
this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_02', 998);                
img_01._x = img_01._y = img_02._x = img_02._y = 20;               

var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();                 
var listener:Object = new Object();                  
listener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip){ }
listener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip,numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) { }
listener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
    if(target_mc._name == 'img_01'){
        img_02._visible = false;
    } else {   
        img_01._visible = false;
    }      
}

var interval:Number = setInterval(load_image, 1000);
function load_image() { 
    loader.addListener(listener);          
    loader.loadClip("http//google.flower.php", _root['img_0'+current_loader]);
    current_loader = current_loader == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    current_img = current_img == images.length - 1 ? 0 : current_img + 1;
}
load_image();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass values to a swf file, you can use `FlashVars` like this :

**In your Object code :**

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="my_swf.swf" width="400" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="my_swf.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="var_passed_from_html=example" />
    <!-- other params -->
</object>
```

**Embed code (if used) :**

```
<embed src="my_swf.swf" flashvars="var_passed_from_html=example" <!-- other params --> />
```

For ActionScript 2, in your swf you can get that value directly like any other variable :

```
trace(var_passed_from_html);    // gives : example
```

For more details, take a look on how to [pass variables to SWFs](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html).

Hope that can help.

**Edit :**

Example :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="my_swf.swf" width="400" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="my_swf.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="img_url=http://www.example.com" />
    <!-- other params -->
</object>
```

AS2 code :

```
var image_url:String = 'empty'; // set a default value

if(img_url){    // if we have received an image url from HTML
    image_url = img_url;
}

function load_image() {         
    if(image_url != 'empty'){   // if image_url is not "empty", load it
        loader.addListener(listener);          
        loader.loadClip(image_url, _root['img_0'+current_loader]);
        current_loader = current_loader == 1 ? 2 : 1;
        current_img = current_img == images.length - 1 ? 0 : current_img + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already done the html part . I  have to change the value of  Loader.loadClip(" &&&&& ").. i have to pass it from html.   i want to know .. what change should be in the .fla(Over Written)

Comment: @TheTricker If in your html you did : `<param name="flashvars" value="img_url=http://www.example.com" />`, in your AS2 code you can do : `loader.loadClip(img_url, ...)`. It's better to use another var to do some controls for your `img_url` var before using it.

Comment: @TheTricker I added an example, take a look.